# Run a command for each element in an array from a file

Tags: arrays, bash

I have an AWS environment where I need the json config files of the security groups. I have thought about finding the `GroupID` and then creating file with just the ID's. From here I would like to pass the created file into an array and use the command;

`aws ec2 describe-security-groups --group-ids $<name> > $<name>.json` to create `n` amount of json files. I have used another post https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/70934/bash-reading-txt-file-and-storing-in-array to read the contents of the file into the array. What I need is to now use the above command to create the json files.

I think it's done at `[[ ${a[$i-1]} = $name ]] && echo "${a[$i]}"` but I'm not sure as I don't really understand the array..

```
#!/bin/bash

# get security-group id's from aws and create a file
 aws ec2 describe-security-groups | grep -i groupid | sort -bdu > sg-names-unsorted.txt

# clear leading/trailing text so only sg's remain & cleanup
  cat sg-names-unsorted.txt | sed 's/^[ \t]*//;s/[ \t]*$//' > output.txt
  cat output.txt | sed 's/\"GroupId": "//;s/"\t*$//' > sg-names.txt
  rm sg-names-unsorted.txt output.txt

 IFS=$'\n' a=($(cat sg-names.txt))
 for i in $(seq ${#a[*]}); do
    [[ ${a[$i-1]} = $name ]] && echo "${a[$i]}"
done

 #aws ec2 describe-security-groups --group-ids $name > $name.json
```

Comment: So what is not working here? and what is the expected output you need? Show us with an actual example

Comment: I think this line `[[ ${a[$i-1]} = $name ]] && echo "${a[$i]}"` needs to incorporate this command `aws ec2 describe-security-groups --group-ids $name > $name.json`. It may even need the `echo` I'm not sure.

Comment: It is absolutely not clear what is in the array `a`, `$name` and how would you like to get that command incorporated

Comment: Hmm. We can probably find a more representative title for this -- it's *not* asking how to create a single command from an array (which would be a different question with a different answer).

Comment: I'm using @randomir answer below

Comment: Yes, that's a great answer. The question title still should be improved. The goal is to have a Q&A database that helps everyone; that means quality of the questions so other people with the same problem can find them is important.

Comment: Most people who ask how to build a command in an array are looking for something like [BashFAQ #5's advice on using an array to construct a single command](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/050#I.27m_constructing_a_command_based_on_information_that_is_only_known_at_run_time) -- this won't help them.

Comment: (The new title is still misleading. You're not creating a single command from an array **at all**! You're looping over array contents, running a separate command for each element).

Comment: Is "how do I run a command for each element in an array?" something you would agree is accurate?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Assuming you have group names in `sg-names.txt`, one name per line, you can use `mapfile` builtin command (available [since `bash 4.0`](http://wiki.bash-hackers.org/scripting/bashchanges#other_builtins_and_keywords)) to load those names into an indexed array, and then a simple `for` loop to iterate over:

```
#!/bin/bash
mapfile groups < sg-names.txt
for group in "${groups[@]}"; do
    echo "Processing group: $group"
    aws ec2 describe-security-groups --group-ids "$group" > "$group.json"
done
```

In case `mapfile` is not available on your system, you could use a combination of `read` and `while` loop:

```
#!/bin/bash
while read group; do
    echo "Processing group: $group"
    aws ec2 describe-security-groups --group-ids "$group" > "$group.json"
done < sg-names.txt
```

To simplify (and make it more robust) the first part of your script (parsing group names from a JSON response), you can use [`jq`](https://stedolan.github.io/jq/) instead of the fragile `grep`/`sed` combo.

With `jq` in place, for example, your script would look:

```
#!/bin/bash
aws ec2 describe-security-groups | jq -r '.SecurityGroups[].GroupId' | while read group; do
    echo "Processing group: $group"
    aws ec2 describe-security-groups --group-ids "$group" > "$group.json"
done
```

Comment: I cannot get `mapfile` to work on OSX or on my Amazon Linux AMI (both are up to date). I get `./sg-check.sh: line 16: mapfile: command not found` as it's not installed. Any ideas where to find it as a `yum install mapfile` yields nothing on the AMI

Comment: Oh, `mapfile` is available since `bash 4.0`. I'll update the answer with an alternative.

Comment: On the AMI; bash --version
GNU bash, version 4.2.46(2)-release (x86_64-redhat-linux-gnu)
Copyright (C) 2011 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
License GPLv3+: GNU GPL version 3 or later <http://gnu.org/licenses/gpl.html>

Comment: which mapfile
/usr/bin/which: no mapfile in (/usr/local/bin:/bin:/usr/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/opt/aws/bin:/home/ec2-user/.local/bin:/home/ec2-user/bin)

Comment: `mapfile` is a builtin command, so `which` can't find it, but `type mapfile` should (see my update).

Comment: Also -- if you run your script with `sh yourscript`, it won't have `mapfile` -- make sure you're executing it as `./yourscript` (which honors the `#!/bin/bash` shebang) or `bash yourscript`. (If you were using a `#!/bin/sh` shebang, that would break it too).

Comment: FYI the `cat output.txt | sed 's/\"GroupId": "//;s/"\t*,$//' > sg-names.txt` doesn't work as it leaves in trailing `"` the one I had seems to do the trick, but thank you, you've been a great help

Comment: @eekfonky, ...you **really** shouldn't be trying to generate JSON with `sed`. Use `jq`.

Comment: @eekfonky, I agree with Charles, have a look at `jq` for parsing JSON.

Comment: I am using sed to cut out all but the `security group id`. The `aws` command creates the json with the `>` redirect

Comment: so you're exacting text from JSON with sed? That's still a job for `jq`. `jq -r '.[].GroupId'` will emit the group id string from each dict in the top-level array, if in fact that's your data structure (a list of dictionaries, each of which has a GroupId key).

Comment: @eekfonky, actually, looking at the AWS docs, what you want might be `jq -r '.SecurityGroups[].GroupId'`. That's going to be much more robust than the `sed` -- it'll work even if the indentation/whitespace/formatting in the JSON that AWS emits changes.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy, I was just editing my answer to add `jq` line, when I saw your comment, thanks.